# Convert regex capturing group from uppercase underscore to camel case

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

One of these days I'm going to learn `sed`, I swear.
Now, to the question:

I'm trying to replace the capturing group of a regex from uppercase underscore (MY_EXAMPLE) to camel case (myExample).

Unfortunately, my sed knowledge is pretty much limited, this is what I have so far:

`cat Labels.h | gsed -E 's/NSLocalizedString\(\@"(.*)", nil\)/\L\1/'`

This converts MY_EXAMPLE to my_example, close, sort of, but not quite. So, the problem I'm facing now is, because the camel case replacement is itself a regex, how can I apply that regex to the capturing group (\1)? Is this easier done with grep or awk?

UPDATE:

To make it more clear, what I'm looking after is every construct like this:

`NSLocalizedString(@"SOMETHING_HERE", nil)`, `NSLocalizedString(@"SOMETHING_ELSE_HERE", nil)` etc

to become

`somethingHere`, `somethingElseHere` etc

Now I got:

`something_here`, `something_else_here` etc

Comment: sed only has 3 commands you should ever use - s, g, and p (with -n), so it's very easy to learn. If you find yourself considering using any other constructs, do yourself a favor and just use awk.

Comment: Are you looking to extract those strings or change them in-place? I mean is your desired output REALLY just `someThingHere` or is it actually `NSLocalizedString(@"someThingHere", nil)`? How can a script tell that "SOMETHING" should become "someThing" (i.e. capitalise the letter "T" mid-word)?

Comment: @EdMorton ups, that's a typo, updated, sorry!

Comment: And the output is really just those selected strings not the whole line?

Comment: See my updated answer given your clarified requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is ok. here you go:

```
kent$  echo 'FOO_BAR
MY_EXAMPLE'|sed -r 's/([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)/\L\1\u\2/'
fooBar
myExample
```

**EDIT**

there is one for your updated question:

```
awk -v FPAT='[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)+' '$0=tolower($1)' file|sed -r 's/_(.)/\u\1/g'
```

I know that `sed` and `awk` don't need work together in 99.9% cases. And the above line could be written in one awk line for sure. but piping to sed saved `split()/substr()` in awk. If performance isn't an issue, you can use it.

another "stupid" combination is `grep|sed(or awk)`. grep the part you need, and pass to awk/sed.

```
grep -Po '[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)+' file
```

does that.

If you do need a single process, I can update the answer in a single awk one-liner.

btw, gnu awk .

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
NSLocalizedString(@"SOMETHING_HERE", nil),
NSLocalizedString(@"SOMETHING_ELSE_HERE", nil) etc

kent$  awk -v FPAT='[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)+' '$0=tolower($1)' f|sed -r 's/_(.)/\u\1/g'
somethingHere
somethingElseHere
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. However, this converts *any* uppercase to camel case. What I'm looking for is to replace only the  capturing group from my previous regex: `NSLocalizedString\(\@"(.*)", nil\)` I'll update my answer to be clearer

Comment: @ValentinRadu can you paste one complete input line as example? if you had gnu sed, it could do that. but awk may do that simpler.

Comment: updated my question. I was hoping to be possible, to avoid a day of hard labor (manually replacing all the strings) :) Worst case scenario, I'll write a python script, however, I would love to do it in sed/grep/awk.

Comment: I see this answer was accepted. Whatever happened to the requirement `replace only the capturing group from my previous regex: NSLocalizedString\(\@"(.*)", nil\)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
MY_EXAMPLE
THIS_IS_ANOTHER_EXAMPLE
and_YET_ANother
NSLocalizedString(@"SOMETHING_HERE", nil)
NSLocalizedString(@"SOMETHING_ELSE_HERE", nil)

$ cat tst.awk         
BEGIN { fn = "NSLocalizedString(@\""; fnLgth = length(fn) }

fnStart = index($0,fn) {

    argStart = fnStart + fnLgth

    argLgth = index(substr($0,argStart),"\"") - 1

    arg = tolower(substr($0,argStart,argLgth))

    split(arg,argA,/_/)

    printf "%s", argA[1]
    for (i=2;i in argA;i++) {
         printf "%s", toupper(substr(argA[i],1,1)) substr(argA[i],2)
    }
    print ""

}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
somethingHere
somethingElseHere
```